How to extend the core row model
I have a tanstack react-tables project and I wanted to add some extra functionality to the row model, to be able to store some metadata and functions to interact with that data.
I had thought I got it right, but i've created some incorrect behavior doing this.
Here is my custom row model:
import {
  getCoreRowModel,
} from '@tanstack/react-table';

const customRowModelFunction = (table) => {
  let model = getCoreRowModel()

  let newmodel = model(table)();

  // Iterate over rows and add custom functions or metadata
  for (const row of newmodel.rows) {

    row.meta = {
      saved: false
    };

    //set the saved state for 2 seconds
    row.rowSaved = () => {
      row.meta.saved = true
      setTimeout(() => {
        row.meta.saved = false
      }, 2000)
    }
    row.getIsSaved = () => row.meta.saved
  }

  return () => newmodel;
};

export default customRowModelFunction;

I've simply added some functionality so that I can style a row when it's data has been saved.
I then add it to my table like this:
import customRowModel from 'Utils/react-table/customRowModel';
const table = useReactTable({
    ...
    getCoreRowModel: customRowModel
})

This appeared to work for a time, but I realized after some hair pulling that my custom model was causing my rows to not update.
Specifially the values returned by table.getRowModel() that I use to itterate through and create my rows. Even though the table data was being updated, the rows from this function never changed from their original state.
Can someone point my in the direction I need to correctly extend the row model? There's not really any documentation on this.
